# How to properly translate Paperclip error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, paperclip

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and the Paperclip plugin. Since I would like to translate Paperclip error messages, I use the following code:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_attachment_size :picture,
    :less_than => 4.megabytes,
    :message   => I18n.t('trl_too_big_file_size', :scope => 'activerecord.errors.messages')
end
```

My `.yml` files are:

```
# <APP_PATH>/config/locales/en.yml (english language)
activerecord:
  errors:
    messages:
      trl_too_big_file_size: is too big

# <APP_PATH>/config/locales/it.yml (italian language)
activerecord:
  errors:
    messages:
      trl_too_big_file_size: è troppo grande
```

My `ApplicationController` is:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    # I am using code from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale.
    I18n.locale = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
  end
  # BTW: My `I18n.default_locale` is `:en` (english).
end
```

However, *when I submit the form related to the Paperclip attachment my application generate a **not** translated text* - that is, it generates (and outputs) a *not* properly translated string because it refers always to the default locale languages error string `en.activerecord.errors.messages.trl_too_big_file_size` even if the `I18n.locale` is `:it`. I made some research (for example, [1](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/14), [2](http://blog.patrickespake.com/2009/11/18/ruby-on-rails-paperclip-com-i18n/)), but I still cannot figure out how to properly translate error messages related to the Paperclip gem in model files (see the code above). It seems a bug of the Parperclip gem (also because that seems that I am not the only one to get this issue)...

How can I solve the issue?

---

P.S.: I think the problem is related to some "*file loading order* process" of ApplicationController-Paperclip gem... but I do not know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I tried using both solutions in the answers, but the first one didn't work at all (apparently ActiveRecord I18n is still not really supported in Paperclip) and the lambda translates the message (i.e. "must be at most %{max] kilobytes"), but the model and attribute names are not translated although I do have them in the YAML file.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a lambda in the message parameter can't you simply use the appropriate key in the YAML file?  Specifically, wouldn't something like:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_attachment_size :picture,
    :less_than => 4.megabytes
end
```

with an entry in the Italian locale YAML file that looks like

```
it:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        article:
          attributes:
            picture:
              less_than: è troppo grande
```

with a similar entry in the English local YAML file

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        article:
          attributes:
            picture:
              less_than: is too big
```

Assuming your locale is getting set correctly, and that other ActiveRecord localized messages are getting displayed correctly, then I'd expect this to work as Paperclip's validators use the underlying ActiveRecord message bundles via the I18n.t method.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to use a lambda for the message?

see https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/411

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_attachment_size :picture,
    :less_than => 4.megabytes,
    :message => lambda { 
      I18n.t('trl_too_big_file_size', :scope => 'activerecord.errors.messages') 
    }
end
```

Comment: I do not understand why, but sometime your code (by using `lambda` functions) seems to work and sometime it seems not. How can I be sure that translations works as expected?

Comment: @Backo: Your version doesn't work because your `I18n.t` call is evaluated when the class is loaded and then you'll have the default locale in place; the lambda version executes the lambda when the message is needed so `I18n.t` gets executed when the message is needed and the locale should be properly set. If the lambda version doesn't work sometimes then you're probably not setting the locale properly sometimes.